# Create NumPy with unique object instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to use `numpy.full()` to create a `numpy.ndarray` full of unique instances of a custom class that I have. My current attempt is:

```
import numpy as np
from custom_class import CustomClass

size_x = 4
size_y = 5

my_array = np.full((size_x, size_y), CustomClass('value'))
```

The issue is that when I run that chunk of code, the output is a `numpy.ndarray` that contains references to `size_x` x `size_y` of the same object. Looking at sample output:

```
array([[<hexgridcell.HexGridCell object at 0x000001C3B5B18BE0>,
        <hexgridcell.HexGridCell object at 0x000001C3B5B18BE0>,
        <hexgridcell.HexGridCell object at 0x000001C3B5B18BE0>,
        <hexgridcell.HexGridCell object at 0x000001C3B5B18BE0>, ...
```

The addresses listed there all clearly point to the same place in memory, and a further investigation concludes that they are indeed pointing to the same object instance. How can I get a `numpy.ndarray` filled this way with unique instances?

Comment: `full` puts the same object every where.    You have to call the object creator fresh for each element, same as if you were creating a list.

Comment: you are giving second argument as a single value which will be repeated. Instead try `np.fromfunction(lambda x, y: CustomClass('value'), (size_x, size_y))`

Comment: Why not just use a list? Why use numpy here at all?

Comment: It makes no sense to use numpy here. Almost certainly you can't do anything vectorized unless there's some really funky tricks going on that I don't know about. It's just going to default to `object` type and be less flexible than a list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I wanted to use numpy for some performance/syntax advantages down the line. The actual application is very resource intensive.

Comment: @questionable_code you'll get none if you're inserting python objects. Numpy just doesn't work like that

Comment: @roganjosh Understood.

Comment: @roganjosh, `np.frompyfunc` can provide some  (2x) speed advantages when working with objects and object dtype arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj what's the source for this? For custom python objects where you're having to access attributes?

Answer (score 0):

A sample class:   (A good question would provide something like this)

```
    In [100]: class Foo(): 
     ...:     def __init__(self, i,j): 
     ...:         self.val = (i,j) 
     ...:     def __repr__(self): 
     ...:         return 'Foo {}'.format(self.val) 
     ...:                                                                                
In [101]: a = Foo(1,2)                                                                   
In [102]: a                                                                              
Out[102]: Foo (1, 2)
```

`full` puts the same thing in all slots - of course since `Foo` is called only once.

```
In [103]: np.full((2,3), Foo(1,2))                                                       
Out[103]: 
array([[Foo (1, 2), Foo (1, 2), Foo (1, 2)],
       [Foo (1, 2), Foo (1, 2), Foo (1, 2)]], dtype=object)
```

In previous questions I've found that `frompyfunc` to be handy, and up to 2x faster (than more explicit numpy loops):

```
In [104]: f = np.frompyfunc(Foo, 2,1)                                                    
In [105]: f(np.arange(3)[:,None], np.arange(4))                                          
Out[105]: 
array([[Foo (0, 0), Foo (0, 1), Foo (0, 2), Foo (0, 3)],
       [Foo (1, 0), Foo (1, 1), Foo (1, 2), Foo (1, 3)],
       [Foo (2, 0), Foo (2, 1), Foo (2, 2), Foo (2, 3)]], dtype=object)
```

A list approach:

```
In [107]: [[Foo(i,j) for j in range(4)] for i in range(3)]                               
Out[107]: 
[[Foo (0, 0), Foo (0, 1), Foo (0, 2), Foo (0, 3)],
 [Foo (1, 0), Foo (1, 1), Foo (1, 2), Foo (1, 3)],
 [Foo (2, 0), Foo (2, 1), Foo (2, 2), Foo (2, 3)]]
```

Some timings:

```
In [108]: timeit f(np.arange(3)[:,None], np.arange(4))                                   
14.3 µs ± 469 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [109]: timeit [[Foo(i,j) for j in range(4)] for i in range(3)]                        
7.59 µs ± 18.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [110]: timeit np.array([[Foo(i,j) for j in range(4)] for i in range(3)])              
31.3 µs ± 1.69 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Doing something useful with the object array may be awkward.  To get the `val`, of all elements, we have to use something like:

```
In [115]: np.frompyfunc(lambda obj: obj.val,1,1)(_105)                                   
Out[115]: 
array([[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)],
       [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
       [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]], dtype=object)
```

or the first element of each tuple:

```
In [116]: np.frompyfunc(lambda obj: obj.val[0],1,1)(_105).astype(int)                    
Out[116]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy.full` will generate an array with the same object in each "cell". For things such as numbers this works fine as the number `1` is still a number `1` anywhere. However, since you want to have a different class object in each cell you will need to generate each object that many times.

Now, if you are using a custom class rather than a data type such as integers or floats, it's better to use plain Python arrays. This is because the numpy arrays are optimized for such data. To do this use something like the following generator.

```
[[CustomClass('value') for j in range(size_x)] for i in range(size_y)]
```

If you absolutely need to use your custom class, you might want to build in some math functions to the class. To do this Python uses things called "magic methods". Something like addition could be implemented using the `__add__` class function. This should allow things such as adding together two arrays to work rather than throwing type errors. More information on [magic methods here](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/#operators). The following is an example of that.

```
class CustomClass:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def __add__(self, second):
    return self.value + second.value
```

Using this definition the following code will add two numpy arrays of these object. However this will also work for plain Python arrays so again the only reason to use numpy is for larger data manipulation such as array resizing and dot product multiplication.

```
array1 = [[CustomClass(i) for j in range(size_x)] for i in range(size_y)]
array2 = [[CustomClass(j*2) for j in range(size_x)] for i in range(size_y)]

array3 = array1 + array2
print(array3)
```

Comment: I don't see how `fromfunction` helps.  Look at `array1`.  I think it will be one `CustomClass` with an array `value`.